# image_style_url doesn't create images

Tags: 7, theming, media

I am using [image_style_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/image_style_url/7) to get a thumbnail of a picture I added through the administrator interface.

```
// $foo->field_picture['und'][0]['uri'] has value public://foo.jpg
image_style_url('foo-thumb', $foo->field_picture['und'][0]['uri']);
```

The API states that the image will be created when the URL is requested. However, when visiting the page the image isn't displayed (404). The URL returned from the function seems to be well formed, but the file hasen't been created.

The 'foo-thumb' folder is in the public data folder and the file permissions should be OK. I tried flushing the image cache (drupal image-flush foo-thumb) but still no results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From: https://drupal.org/drupal-7.20-release-notes

> In addition, any code which programmatically generates a link to an
> image derivative without using the standard image_style_url() API
> function will no longer work correctly if the image does not already
> exist in the file system, since the necessary token will not be
> present in the URL.

Instead you can do something like this;

```
$image_uri      = $node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri']; // or any public://my_image
$style          = 'my_style';
$derivative_uri = image_style_url($style, $image_uri);
$success        = file_exists($derivative_uri) || image_style_create_derivative(image_style_load($style), $image_uri, $derivative_uri);

$new_image_url  = file_create_url($derivative_uri);
```

Comment: Shoud there not be an if at the end? ie: 

if ($success) { 
  $new_image_url  = file_create_url($derivative_uri);
}

Comment: A little update for the `image_style_create_derivative` the `$style` variable should be array `$style = image_style_load('my_style');`

Comment: I've edited the answer to pass `$style` though `image_style_load()` before passing to `image_style_create_derivative()` as per the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_create_derivative/7).

Comment: Everything worked in this except that file_create_url($derivative_uri); did not work for me.    What did work was substituting that (on the last line) with image_style_url($style, $image_uri);

Comment: This method of file_create_url does not apply image style. I found a solution that applying another image style. Really strange.

Comment: I have tried this code but the variable $success never returned TRUE. 

I had to use image_style_path() to get the path and used this path in image_style_create_derivative() to generate cached images. 

Here is My Code: 

$image_uri = $image['uri'];
$style = 'gallery_thumbnail';
$derivative_uri = image_style_url($style, $image_uri);
$path = image_style_path('gallery_thumbnail', $image_uri);
$success = file_exists($derivative_uri) || image_style_create_derivative(image_style_load($style), $image_uri, $path);

Hope it helps for someone.

Answer (score 7):

One common mistake is that URIs are not properly formatted. Check that your URI parameter is prefixed with `public://`.

## Bad Practice

```
$imageUrl = image_style_url('style_name', 'myimage.jpg');
$imageUrl = image_style_url('style_name', $node->field_x[$node->language][0]['filename']);
```

This outputs a URL to the styled image (with image token), but does not generate a styled image when it hasn't been previously generated.

---

## Good Practice

```
$imageUrl = image_style_url('style_name', file_build_uri('myimage.jpg')); // changes to 'public://myimage.jpg'
$imageUrl = image_style_url('style_name', $node->field_x[$node->language][0]['uri']);
```

This outputs a styled URL, like the above, and generates a styled image if none exists.

Answer (score 1):

The public file system path was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the theme function.

```
$img = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'your_image_style_machine_name', 'path' => $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']));
```

Rather than returning the URL it will return the html for the img.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fid = file_load($field_yuorfield_fid);          
$image_uri = image_style_url('yuor_style', $fid->uri);
fopen($image_uri, 'r');
```

here can use url for create html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `foo-thumb` style, you can check at `admin/config/media/image-styles`.

The first parameters of [image_style_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/image_style_url/7) is a **style name**, not a **folder** name.

Comment: The style exists, the folder name is the same as the style name in my case.

Comment: If you got the error 404, that mean the menu doesnot exist. I think all of your image styles have this problem.

Can you explain more about you Drupal version and information:
- What webserver you are using?
- Is clean url setting is correct?

Comment: I don't know if the menu doesn't exist, but the file surely doesn't. The URL returned seems about right, but if I check my folder on the server the image isn't there. The folder created by Drupal ('foo-thumb') is there though. Running Apache 2.2 with clean URLs and all seem to be working fine.

Comment: I can see your image generate link was not found. Can you check the .htaccess file to check the line `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`, are you running Drupal on top of your domain?

Other try is install [imagemagick](http://drupal.org/project/imagemagick) toolkit but i see your problem isnot problem by the image render of php.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a 404 when trying to view the image, a possibility is that the image style name is not correct. In my case, the style name that showed up in Image Styles was not the machine name of the style name. When hovering over the style the url will display the machine name of the style name. Either change it to the machine name or delete the current and recreate with the name needed.