# Image style in views field template on image

Tags: theming, media

I'm struggling with a piece of code in my views field template.

A short overview of the situation:

- Node product has a field with filename for an image
- Images are added with filezilla in default/files/products

What is the best way to implement image styles on these images.
My code:

```
<?php
 print theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'product_overzicht', 'path' => $img_url)); 
?>
```

Where $img_url is just a simple variable, like: img_filename.jpg

This doesn't work because the folder of that image style is empty. I know the easy way is to use an image field on my product node but this can't be done here. I use a excel import for all products and the image filename is a column in that excel file. Images are all together in a folder.

Does anybody know a way do this or a good workaround. CSS markup is not good because the image size needs to be as low as possible in the view but on de node details page I would like to show the entire image.

Any tips or advice is welcome!

Comment: My first thought would be that your `$img_url` is incomplete. You say the images are uploaded to sites/default/files/products so `$img_url` should be `'products/filename.jpg'` i.e. the path relative to sites/default/files. If the variables supplied to the theme function are correct, Drupal should automatically generate the folder contents during the page request.

Comment: You are correct. I did not apply the URI correct. Thank you for your reaction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
<img src="<?php print image_style_url('product_overzicht', $img_url);?>">
```

Where **$img_url** should be **uri**, which in your case can be : *public://products/img_filename.jpg*

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this but the problem stays. I don't really understand why this would make a difference? Can you explain this a little perhaps, I'm a beginner/junoir in Drupal. Each time I use the image_style_url() function, Drupal looks in the sites/default/product_overzicht folder. But the images are in an other folder.

Comment: Have you checked permissions to folder? When this code executes image_style_url suppose to generate image of style mentioned and return a url for it.

Comment: Check this : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91653/image-style-url-no-longer-creates-images, This can be a reason.

Comment: The permissions are 755 for the product_overzicht folder and 777 for the product_overzicht/public folder. When I compare this to an other image style folder, it looks the same. So I believe this is oke. I"m working on Drupal 7.40 currently. Where do you think I should put my files, now: sites/default/files/producten ? Thank you for the link, but find it quite difficult understanding.

Comment: I must apologise, It was indeed the URI. I thank you a lot sir!