# Drupal cannot generate the derived image ANYMORE?

Tags: 7, caching, media

OK, My situation is really complicated (or Im stupid).
I start my website http://rlsgame.org with Drupal System (even if Im .NET developer)...
After 3 month, my website start grow up (about 2000 article and 3000 members) But a problem appear !!! I didnt touch anything, It appear just like that !!

When I want submit a Node, I have an issue with Images, I cant see the preview image :

[image]

**and After submiting the Node, here is the result:**

[image]

**I refresh the page and the nothing, But after i press CTR+F5, the article is fine:**

[image]

you can check the page here: http://rlsgame.org/PC/Games/ArmA-III
All is fine...

But the big problem is that Drupal System cannot generate the derived image of User Picture !!
Even if I press CTR+F5 like before, the problem is still here, look an exemple of a profile page:

[image]
Link: http://rlsgame.org/users/gamer

The old users profile is fine, because the picture is generated before the problem, exemple:

[image]
Link: http://rlsgame.org/users/mgs

And one more thing it start to appear too, Drupal start Caching comments (not like before this problem), when I post comment, sometimes it apear without Caching, and sometimes I must wait about 10 sec, for exemple, I post a comment and nothing appear, and I navigate to the homepage, and here we go, the msg appears:

[image]

I think if I fix the issue, All those problems will disappear ...

Im looking for fixing that 10 days ago, So Just for info:

- All files permission Are OK:
  sites/default  => 555
  sites/default/files  => 755  (and all sub-folders too including styles)
- And paths of File system are OK
- Drupal is updated to 7.26 (latest version)

And the problem is not from the server (Im working on Shared Server) because I downloaded my website and run it in Local but I see the same problem plus My website work before so the problem is not from the server.

Ah, one thing, when i check Reports Log, I see a lot of warning, here is an exemple:

[image]

Thats all, plz help me to fix that, Im losing traffic....

Thanx for advance.

Comment: Can you confirm exact version of Drupal you are currently using, and site problems?  Look at admin/reports/status for both.

Comment: I edit the topic, the drupal version is 7.26

Comment: From my expirence with those kind of problems it is usualy a permissions problem after all. You wrote that the styles directory has 755 permission (to much in my opinion but nevermind) what about the files? And what about the owner and group? Is it configured right? One more thing -Drupal has an issue about the open_basedir and images - google it and check that it is configured right. (If you can't find it tell me and I'll find it for you..). I just read the above comment about the version, have you updated the .htaccess files with the 7.23 update (or 7.24 I'm not sure)

Comment: What do you mean @Rotem with "owner and group" ?
I didnt update .htaccess, is it required to update .htaccess ?

Comment: The files and directories owner and group... And Drupal 7.23 contains an update to the files, private files and temp files .htaccess have you updated the core recently or you were using 7.26 since the begining?

Comment: @Rotem
Im not using 7.26 since the begining, I just update the core, and kkeeping .htaccess evrytime.
PS: Im sorry if my english is bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your settings.php file add this

```
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
```

In the future you should use [image_style_url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) when using image styles as this will then add in itok parameter for images. Usage: [image_style_url doesn't create images](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/image-style-url-doesnt-create-images/93922#93922)

More info about this: https://drupal.org/drupal-7.21-release-notes

Comment: OK I will try this now, give me 2 min

Comment: To make the answer complete, this is a DDoS protection feature added in Drupal 7.22. Modules using correct APIs should continue to work (or you might need to update them). I used this $conf hack all the time though.

Comment: @slixikou, if you search on this site for "itok" or Google for "drupal itok" you will learn more about the problem.

Comment: Ok guys, how can I edit settings.php, I get permission problem.
I change the settings.php permission to 755 and nothing, always permission error (Im working with cPanel) !!

Comment: OK I edit settings.php, and I add:
$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;
I will check now the result

Comment: @mikeytown2, It works, It works ...
But can someone explain why ? I must understand that problem :D
Thanx again

Comment: And one more thing, if I update Drupal, is it is it required to update .htaccess ?

Comment: No you don't need to update the .htaccess if it is already updated with the recent .htaccess - if it isn't updated the status report would indicate it as a problem. And you wrote that the settings.php has 755 permissions - change it to 440.. It is a security issue

Comment: are you sure 440 and not 644 !!

Comment: Are you sure it's night now? Yes I'm sure.. :) and about the .htaccess - run update.php to make sure that the DB is updated and save the file settings (where you choose the files, temp and private directories paths..) It will make sure that your .htaccess is up to date.

Comment: update.php will not verify that your .htaccess is up to date; and it will not update it either. Changes that need to be done to .htaccess is usually a manual process, unless you overwrite it when updating core. 440 for settings.php is correct. If you visit the status page `admin/reports/status` that will attempt to change it to 440, so hit that page first and then see if the permissions still need to be fixed.

Comment: Update.php will show a warning about the .htaccess, and as I said when you save the configuration on the file settings page it will update the .htaccess *auto.* - read https://drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003

Comment: OK guys thanx and thank you @Rotem for your help ;)

Comment: But One thing Guys, All problems that I said in my Post are resolved bcz of @mikeytown2 exept Caching Comment.
Why Comments still using the Cache, when some one post comment, he must wait about 10 sec then refresh the page to see her comment !!

Comment: !! strange !! sometimes comments use Cache, and sometimes not !!

Comment: Are they posting the comments as anon., auth or both?

Comment: @Rotem, no just auth users. and thanx for reply

Comment: so @Rotem do you have an idea about the problem ?