# How to programmatically create an image style?

Tags: 7, media

I need to create image style programmatically in Drupal 7. I found this issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2735969 and much more other issues, but all are for Drupal 8. I can't find anything to Drupal 7. Is that impossible in Drupal 7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [image\_style\_url doesn't create images](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/image-style-url-doesnt-create-images)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I want to programmatically create image style with its machine name and settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`image_style_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_style_save/7.x) and [`image_effect_save`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/image_effect_save/7.x) functions.

An example from the comments on the `image_style_save` docs page:

```
$style = image_style_save(array('name' => 'avatar'));
$effect = array(
  'name' => 'image_scale',
  'data' => array(
    'width' => 64,
    'height' => 64,
    'upscale' => TRUE,
  ), 
  'isid' => $style['isid'],
);
image_effect_save($effect);
```

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you! :)